# Lead-acid battery charging: current not dropping

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid

I am charging a 24 V lead-acid battery with 20 A and a 28.2 V limit. I have two batteries where the current is not dropping and the voltage stays at 25 V.

Does it mean the battery has short circuited? How can I check it?

Comment: Is any cell bubbling during charge?

Answer (score 4):

That does sound like you have a shorted cell.

If these are normal flooded cell batteries, look in the individual cells for electrolyte level and bubbling.  If one cell has significantly more electrolyte than the others, and is not bubbling, it is probably shorted.

I assume you have two, 12 volt batteries - a battery with a shorted cell will have a lower voltage than one without a shorted cell.

In any case, both (all?) batteries should be replaced.  It is best if all batteries in a bank are same make, type, vintage, and usage history.

Comment: I am charging a forklift traction battery. Its made up of 12 cells 2V each so 24V in total. When I measure each cell they all have similar voltages. I will try checking what you suggested (bubbling). Anyway its not wise to replace just one cell right? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

as above  -  you have a fault in the batteries  -  if Pb-acid and  > 5 years old  -  throw them out  ->  new ones